# How can I average the sum of detail field values and put the result in the header

Tags: acumatica

I have a field in the detail / grid section of a custom screen that I want to essentially average (sum divided by row count), and then display this value in the header section.  I can't seem to find any examples of how to do this with a PXFormula field.  If I need to use the RowSelected event (or FieldUpdating event) then so be it, but I was hoping to do this with the PXFormula field.

Comment: You can do it, but will need to create Count operator. See example by the following link https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/05/scalarcount-bql-operator.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it this way:

```
    protected virtual void xTACProjectMaster_RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
    {
        Decimal? totPctComplete = 0;
        int rowCount = 0;

        var pj = e.Row as xTACProjectMaster;
        if (pj != null)
        {
            PXResultset<xTACProjectTask> res = PXSelect<xTACProjectTask,
                                               Where<xTACProjectTask.projectID, Equal<Required<xTACProjectTask.projectID>>>>.Select(this, pj.ProjectID);

            foreach (PXResult<xTACProjectTask> rec in res)
            {
                xTACProjectTask pt = rec;
                totPctComplete += pt.PctComplete;
                rowCount++;
            }

            if(rowCount > 0)
                pj.PctComplete = totPctComplete / rowCount;
        }
    }
```